# When to use asObservable() in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am wondering what is the use of [`asObservable`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/asobservable.md):

As per docs:

> An observable sequence that hides the identity of the
>   source sequence.

But why would you need to hide the sequence?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

### When to use Subject.prototype.asObservable()

The purpose of this is to prevent leaking the "observer side" of the Subject out of an API. Basically to prevent a leaky abstraction when you don't want people to be able to "next" into the resulting observable.

#### Example

(NOTE: This really isn't how you should make a data source like this into an Observable, instead you should use the `new Observable` constructor, See below).

```js
const myAPI = {
  getData: () => {
    const subject = new Subject();
    const source = new SomeWeirdDataSource();
    source.onMessage = (data) => subject.next({ type: 'message', data });
    source.onOtherMessage = (data) => subject.next({ type: 'othermessage', data });
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
};
```

Now when someone gets the observable result from `myAPI.getData()` they can't `next` values in to the result:

```js
const result = myAPI.getData();
result.next('LOL hax!'); // throws an error because `next` doesn't exist
```

#### You should usually be using `new Observable()`, though

In the example above, we're probably creating something we didn't mean to. For one, `getData()` isn't lazy like most observables, it's going to create the underlying data source `SomeWeirdDataSource` (and presumably some side effects) immediately. This also means if you `retry` or `repeat` the resulting observable, it's not going to work like you think it will.

It's better to encapsulate the creation of your data source within your observable like so:

```js
const myAPI = {
  getData: () => return new Observable(subscriber => {
    const source = new SomeWeirdDataSource();
    source.onMessage = (data) => subscriber.next({ type: 'message', data });
    source.onOtherMessage = (data) => subscriber.next({ type: 'othermessage', data });
    return () => {
      // Even better, now we can tear down the data source for cancellation!
      source.destroy();
    };
  });
}
```

With the code above, any behavior, including making it "not lazy" can be composed on top of the observable using RxJS's existing operators.

Comment: TX Ben... been following your stuff... tx for all the great support on RX

Comment: then how to get value after var result = myAPI.getData();

Comment: @Shardul... you'd subscribe to result: `result.subscribe(value => doSomething(value))`

Comment: Does anyone know if this creates a new reference? i.e. if returning form a service would it create a new observable from the subject each time?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Yes, each time you `return subject.asObservable();` it would be a new observable. You'd have a single Subject member variable, and the onMessage/onOtherMessage would be declared in a condition, or at initialization (not every call). I've used that approach, with a `pipe( filter() )` based on a parameter supplied to the `getData()` function. The

Comment: @BenLesh what if I create the subject outside getData() and just return observable everytime getData() is called from the same subject instance? is it multicasting rather the current impl where each new subject is created and only once observable will be returned for that subject for each call to getData()

Comment: @BenLesh, in your second code sample is `subject` supposed to be `subscriber` ?

Comment: I would also like verification here : should the `subject.next` lines be `subscriber`. Also, "if you retry or repeat the resulting observable, it's not going to work like you think it will." Can you be more specific? Do you just mean `new SomeWeirdDataSource()` is going to happen every time `getData` is called and that by wrapping it in `new Observable` you make that instantiation wait until a subscription. I guess I don't see when you would call `getData` without a `.subscribe` so I'm missing the value there. Finally, what do you foresee happening to "tear down the data source"? Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

A **`Subject`** can act both as an **`observer`** and an **`observable`**.

An **`Observable`** has 2 methods.

- *subscribe*
- *unsubscribe*

Whenever you *subscribe* to an **`observable`**, you get an **`observer`** which has *next*, *error* and *complete* methods on it.

You'd need to hide the sequence because you don't want the stream source to be publicly available in every component. You can refer to `@BenLesh`'s example, for the same.

P.S. : When I first-time came through Reactive Javascript, I was not able to understand **`asObservable`**. Because I had to make sure I understand the basics clearly and then go for **`asObservable`**. :)

Comment: this might be a silly question but why don't we create an Observable in the first case instead of creating a Subject?

Comment: @WaleedAhmad because internally you might need to update the Subject's value by calling Next.

Answer (score 7):

### (Typescript Only) Use Types Instead of asObservable()

I like what [Alex Vayda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69103339/11308345) is saying about using types instead, so I'm going to add some additional information to clarify.

---

If you use asObservable(), then you are ***running*** the following code.

```ts
/**
 * Creates a new Observable with this Subject as the source. You can do this
 * to create customize Observer-side logic of the Subject and conceal it from
 * code that uses the Observable.
 * @return {Observable} Observable that the Subject casts to
 */
asObservable(): Observable<T> {
  const observable = new Observable<T>();
  (<any>observable).source = this;
  return observable;
}
```

This is useful for Javascript, but ***not needed in Typescript***. I'll explain why below.

---

### Example

```ts
export class ExampleViewModel {

   // I don't want the outside codeworld to be able to set this INPUT
   // so I'm going to make it private. This means it's scoped to this class
   // and only this class can set it.
   private _exampleData = new BehaviorSubject<ExampleData>(null);

   // I do however want the outside codeworld to be able to listen to
   // this data source as an OUTPUT. Therefore, I make it public so that
   // any code that has reference to this class can listen to this data
   // source, but can't write to it because of a type cast.
   // So I write this
   public exampleData$ = this._exampleData as Observable<ExampleData>;
   // and not this
   // public exampleData$ = this._exampleData.asObservable();
}
```

Both do the samething, but one doesn't add additional code calls or memory allocation to your program.

❌`this._exampleData.asObservable();`❌
Requires additional memory allocation and computation at runtime.

✅`this._exampleData as Observable<ExampleData>;`✅
Handled by the type system and will NOT add additional code or memory allocation at runtime.

---

#### Conclusion

If your colleagues try this, `referenceToExampleViewModel.exampleData$.next(new ExampleData());`,  then it will be caught at compile time and the type system won't let them, because `exampleData$` has been casted to `Observable<ExampleData>` and is no longer of type `BehaviorSubject<ExampleData>`, but they will be able to listen (`.subscribe()`) to that source of data or extend it (`.pipe()`).

This is useful when you only want a particular service or class to be setting the source of information. It also helps with separating the input from the output, which makes debugging easier.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on the _"Requires additional memory allocation and computation at runtime."_ topic? Is it because you create a new instance of an observable?

Comment: Calling .asObservable() runs the code block mentioned above. When a function is called it requires computation cycles on the CPU. Inside that code block is: new Observable<T>().  When the "new" keyword is used, you are allocating memory to store this new object. If you don't use .asObservable, then you save some cpu computation and memory allocation

Comment: You can use .asObservable() in a small program and it won't matter. The amount of computation time and memory allocated is negligible, but if you are working on an enterprise system, and you need all the resources you can get, then casting your BehaviorSubject's to observables using the type system is the way to go

Comment: I feel like I could easily cast it back and use next if that was my intention. Wether that's a problem or not depends on context I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/96766) I would mention that in my opinion it depends on the language in use.

For untyped (or weakly typed) languages like *JavaScript* it might make sense to conceal the source object from the caller by creating a delegate object like `asObservable()` method does. Although if you think about it it won't prevent a caller from doing `observable.source.next(...)`. So this technique doesn't prevent the Subject API from leaking, but it indeed makes it more hidden form the caller.

On the other hand, for strongly typed languages like *TypeScript* the method `asObservable()` doesn't seem to make much sense (if any).
Statically typed languages solve the API leakage problem by simply utilizing the type system (e.g. interfaces). For example, if your `getData()` method is defined as returning `Observable<T>` then you can safely return the original `Subject`, and the caller will get a compilation error if attempting to call `getData().next()` on it.

Think about this modified example:

```js
let myAPI: { getData: () => Observable<any> }

myAPI = {
    getData: () => {
        const subject = new Subject()
        // ... stuff ...
        return subject
    }
}

myAPI.getData().next() // <--- error TS2339: Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'
```

Of course, since it all compiles to *JavaScript* in the end of the day there might still be cases when you want to create a delegate. But my point is that the room for those cases is much smaller then when using vanilla *JavaScript* , and probably in majority of cases you don't need that method.

Comment: Even when considering Javascript only, asObservable still documents your intent of not exposing the Subject for people reading your code.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript or TypeScript? In JS it indeed shows the intent (somewhat), but in TS the intent is communicated via the return type of the function.

Comment: I have probably misread your answer. I agree with you.