# Load generic angular dynamic component

Tags: angular-dynamic-components, angular-v7

I am trying to make a dynamic component for the popup to create view and edit page for different content. I have made a popup component in which I want to pass a new component name and title of the page. However, I am not getting new component data in the popup component. Please have a look at code, if you need any more detail, please ask. Thanks in Advance.

I have tried to inject service in another component and it gets data on button click, but in the popup component, I am not getting data. For now, I am doing just console.log data to popup.component.ts file but there is no result in console.log.

[image: folder structure for the dynamic popup component]

popup.service.ts

```
export class PopupService {
    isShowing = false;
    private popup = new Subject();
    loadingPopup = new Subject();
    outputEmitter = new Subject();
    popupContent: any = {
        isShowing: false,
        content: null,
        contentParams: PopupModel
    }
    constructor() { }
    public getPopup() {
        return this.popup;
    }
    public showLoading(isLoading: boolean = true) {
        this.loadingPopup.next(isLoading);
    }
    public create(component: any, parameters?: PopupModel): any {     
        this.showLoading(true);
        this.popupContent.isShowing = true;
        this.popupContent.content = component;
        this.popupContent.contentParams = parameters;
        this.popup.next(this.popupContent);
        console.log(this.popupContent)
    }
}
```

Popupcomponent.ts

```
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

public popupObservable: Subscription;

constructor(private popupService: PopupService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.popupObservable = this.popupService.getPopup().subscribe((popupContent: any) => {
console.log(popupContent)
//code here to use createDynamicComponent method }
}
private createDynamicComponent(component: Type<any>): void {
//code here using ComponentFactoryResolver and ViewContainerRef to create dynamic component
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.popupObservable && !this.popupObservable.closed) {
      this.popupObservable.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code where the dynamic component is being called and the popup should be created. 
Component.ts

```
AddRecord(){
    this.popupService.create( NewRecordComponent, {
      title: 'Add',
      emitterMethod: 'saved'
    })
  }
```

component.html

```
<button (click)="AddRecord()">Add</button>
```

Comment: It'll be good if you could provide a small replication of you problem. I am personally find it hard to understand the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are not emitting a value from your subject anywhere.
You would need to call [popup.next(popupContent)](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject).

However, I don't think you have the right model here.
If you're not doing any async calls (api, filesystem etc..) in your getPopup method, then just return the popupContent directly

```js
public getPopup() : {} {
        return this.popupContent;
    }
```

You should also define an interface for your popupContent somewhere so you can import it and use a strong interface to avoid runtime errors.

e.g.

```js
export interface IPopupContent {
  isShowing: boolean;
  content: string;
  contentParams: PopupModel;
}
```

Also, don't expose subjects directly, rather expose an observable linked to the subject.

See [When to use asObservable() in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986548/when-to-use-asobservable-in-rxjs)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have called popup.next(popupContent) in popup.service.ts fire in creat() method and that console.log gives me popupContent object.  If I subscribe popup subject in any other component that popup component it self, I get the object. That`s why not getting the exact problem I am occurring.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You will need BehaviourSubject, this stores the last emitted value for future calls to subscribe.