# RxJS6 asObservable() needed on a Subject?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

When is `asObservable()` needed on a Subject (e.g. BehaviorSubject) to get a observable of the subject? The subject isself can be casted to an Observable as well.

#### Questions

1. What are the technical differences between `name1$` and `name2$`?
2. Which one should be used (`name1$` or `name2$`)?

### Code Sample

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class Person {
  private nameSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('lorem');

  public get name1$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.nameSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get name2$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.nameSubject;
  }

  public setName(value: string): void {
    this.nameSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Thank You for your answers in advance!

Comment: When using `asObservable()` you get an error when accessing `next`. When you're casting you can cast the Observable back to a type that let's you call `next`. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qhxv2u

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, it's recommended to use `asObservable()` only when using RxJS in JavaScript. With TypeScript you can use just type casting and it won't let you call `next()` and so on.

```
private nameSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('lorem');
public nameSubject$: Observable<string> = this.nameSubject;
```

This is the officially recommended way of turning Subjects to Observables in TypeScript.
For details see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2408#issuecomment-282077506.

Answer (score 7):

`asObservable()` creates a new Observable, which wraps the `Subject`, so the wrapped observable doesn't have `next()` method, as well as `complete()` and `error()`. I think it makes more sense in JavaScript, where returned object isn't restricted by it's type. But in TypeScript you can hide these methods just by narrowing the type, it should be enough in most cases. You just tell that an `Observable` is returned and a user of the API doesn't know that it's a `Subject`; of course it can be casted back to `Subject`, but that is not how an API should be used.

See also: [When to use asObservable() in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986548/when-to-use-asobservable-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 3):

There is not much difference, with `asObservable()` it mainly just block your access to observer methods - `complete`, `next` , `error` to prevent you from accidentally calling them

```
const a = new Subject();
console.log(a.asObservable().next)
// undefined
```

it is better to return `asObservable()` to be on the safe side if you not using that particular stream as observer