# How to handle undefined Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

In my Angular service I am providing a public Observable called `usageDoc$`.

service.ts:

```
usageDoc$: Observable<IUsage>;

initializeUsageDoc() {
  //gets called in app.component.ts on app load
  ...
  //some async db querying

  this.usageDoc$ = this.firestore.getUsageDoc(user.uid);  //getUsageDoc(..) returns Observable<IUsage>
}
```

component.ts

```
localDoc: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.usageDoc$.subscribe(doc=>this.localDoc=doc);
}
```

This leads to the following error: `cannot read property subscribe of undefined...` as `usageDoc$` is not yet set on the component init. Currently I am using a workaround by creating a second observable `usageDocReady$ = new Subject<boolean>` in service that emits as soon as `usageDoc$` is set.

Is there better to solve this issue? Can I somehow initialize `usageDoc$` with a default value?

I know I would not have this issue if I'd subscribe in template using the async pipe, but I need a normal variable for displaying matters, hence the use of `localDoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1. It'd ensure future subscribers would get the last emission whilst avoiding any `undefined` errors.

```js
private usageDocSrc = new ReplaySubject<IUsage>(1);
public usageDoc$ = this.usageDocSrc.asObservable();

initializeUsageDoc() {
  //gets called in app.component.ts on app load
  ...
  //some async db querying

  this.firestore.getUsageDoc(user.uid).subscribe({
    next: value => this.usageDocSrc.next(value)
  });
}
```

If you don't wish to use a `ReplaySubject`, then I don't understand the need for the `Observable`. You could directly return the observable from `getUsageDoc()` function.

```js
initializeUsageDoc(): Observable<IUsage> {
  //gets called in app.component.ts on app load
  ...
  //some async db querying

  return this.firestore.getUsageDoc(user.uid);
}
```

Although this would invoke all the statements prior to `getUsageDoc()` for each subscription to `initializeUsageDoc()`.

Comment: What's the point of having `usageDoc$` and `usageDocSrc`?

Comment: @BojanKogoj: It's a force of habit using the [`asObservable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/6513921) construct from a multicast like `Subject` or `ReplaySubject`. Some would prefer not using it: `usageDoc$ = new ReplaySubject<IUsage>(1)`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103116/6513921).

Comment: Ok makes sense if you are trying to prevent anyone from nexting from outside service. In this case make `usageDocSrc` private as well?

Comment: @BojanKogoj: Yes that is the convention (or at least it used to be). I've updated the answer.