# Rxjs : prevent pushing data to subjects from outisde the service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

```
Within my anguular app , i ve this service :

@Injectable()
export class myService{

  myBehaviouSubject= new BehaviorSubject("");


  setData(){
     this.myBehaviouSubject.next("123");
  }

}
```

Inside my **app.component**  , i m able to get the value , but i want to keep it **readonly** or editable only inside the service itself , i want to prevent to push any data from component (`.next('DATA')`)

```
    @Component({

    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(public myService : MyService) { }

    getData(){
      // GET VALUE
      this.myService.myBehaviouSubject.value
    }

    unwantedMethodToSetValue(){
           // SET VALUE -> i want to prevent this
           this.myService.myBehaviouSubject.next("unwanted value")

    }

}
```

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: what's your use case to protect the .next()? Could you please provide your reason why this might be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the observable inside service only by declaring it as private field of a class.

```js
@Injectable()
export class myService {

  private myBehaviouSubject = new BehaviorSubject("");

  // Use this observable inside the app component class.
  myBehaviouSubjectObservable = myBehaviouSubject.asObservable();

  setData() {
    this.myBehaviouSubject.next("123");
  }
}

@Component({

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public myService: MyService) {}

  getData() {
    // You can subscribe to observable and can get value here
    this.myService.myBehaviouSubjectObservable.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);
    })
  }

  unwantedMethodToSetValue() {
    // SET VALUE -> you cannot do this here now.
    this.myService.myBehaviouSubject.next("unwanted value")

  }

}
```

Comment: This does not tackle the issue of getting the value, nor as observable nor as direct value.

Comment: I have updated my code with complete description in inline comments. Please let me know if the it resolves your issue or not.

Comment: a note for those who interested in asObservable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/6543507

Answer (score 3):

Use property access modifiers:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService{
  private myValueSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  public readonly myValueObservable: Observable<string> = this.myValueSubject.asObservable();

  public setData() {
     this.myValueSubject.next("123");
  }
  public getData(): string {
    return this.myValueSubject.value;
  }
}
```

Instances of `MyService` will not have a publicly accessible subject.

I usually try to avoid a method like `getData`, favoring subscriptions to the related observable. If I ever find myself writing those kinds of methods, it's a warning flag to re-evaluate my architecture. If you just want to store a value and get/set it with methods, use a plain old private property. The entire purpose of the subject is defeated if you are only ever getting the value through a method like `getData()`

Check out the documentation for typescript classes, which discusses access modifiers: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: This achieves the same thing as my answer except you're able to override myValueObservable on accident. Not sure what extra this contributes ?

Comment: @Boyen Well, I started typing this probably at the same time as you were typing yours. It isn't typical to patrol a question after you've answered and guard it against similar answers. Not sure what that contributes.

Comment: I'm not trying to guard anything. I just attempted to see if your answer contains something mine does not, or if I understand yours wrong, allowing both of us to learn. No need to feel attacked and retaliate.

Comment: And as it turns out, I did understand yours wrong. It does achieve the exact same thing as mine, in a different way. My statement about being able to override myValueObservable was incorrect, as it is marked as readonly. You could have told me that instead of attacking my merits.

Comment: I believe it does not, it just returns the subject typed as an observable ( which is what as Observable does). No new instance is created

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-qiwfms?file=app/app.component.ts I objectively don't.

Comment: I do still see where you're coming from, I've upvoted your answer. Odd conversation we've had. Text does not read emotion well.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional answer : If you return the Subject as an observable, you disallow .next() calls.

But in your case, you also want direct access to the current value without subscribing, so you could add a getter for that too.

```js
@Injectable()
export class myService{

  private readonly myBehaviouSubject = new BehaviorSubject("");


  setData(){
     this.myBehaviouSubject.next("123");
  }
  public get myObservable$(): Observable<string>{
    return this.myBehaviourSubject;
  }
  public get currentValue(): string{
    return this.myBehaviourSubject.value;
  }

}
```

Comment: The `asObservable` is actually redundant, as the TS notation informs, that result is observable thus not having `next` nor `value` properties/functions

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-protected-rxjs-subject

in this solution which I hope meet you needs:

- be aware that there is no subscription
- fetching updates handled manually
- Property 'myBehaviourSubject' is private and only accessible
  within class 'TestService'.

Comment: .. in fact automatic fetchin data wth subscribing seems to be important for me