# How to fix the error next is not a function in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    @Select(UserPageState.get('collection')) users$: BehaviorSubject<Array<Partial<User>>>;


    const USER = this.creds.credentials['id'];
    this.users$.subscribe(param => this.users$.next(param.filter(x => x.id !== USER)));

    await this.store.dispatch(new UserPageList({ start: 1, length: this.pageSize })).toPromise();
    }
```

***ERROR***

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.users$.next is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next
```

***user.ts***

```
  username: string;
  password?: string;
  token: string;
  avatar: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  department: string;
  position: string;
  role: string;
  status: string;
  enabled: boolean;
  groups: Array<Group>;
  location: Array<Sbu>;
```

every time i run the application the error is always next is not a function.
and i tried to change the behavioursubject to BehaviorSubject(Array>);

and all my code is error.

Comment: What's `@Select(UserPageState.get('collection'))`?

Comment: And where is `users$` being set? And won't this cause a stack overflow if you are emitting a value into a subject from within that subject's subscription?

Comment: @KurtHamilton clearly some design flaws here :D. I don't know what `@Select` is, but clearly not an Angular annotation

Comment: 1. BehaviorSubject needs to be initialized with an initial value.
2. It is better to replace `this.users$.subscribe` with `this.users$.asObservable().subscribe`.
3. As others have mentioned, there is a fundamental flaw here. Subscribing to an observable and updating it within itself creates a cyclic lock and will lead to error.

Comment: @Michael D, Please clarify why you suggest using `asObservable()` here.

Comment: @KurtHamilto I used statement

Comment: `"and i tried to change the behavioursubject to BehaviorSubject(Array>);"` Note that changing the type declarations in typescript won't affect the types of the values in runtime. Types in typescript is just a tool to help you at compile time

Comment: @mamichels: please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/6513921).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using [Ngxs](https://www.ngxs.io/) library for state management, with its `Select` decorator to retrieve a slice of state.

`@Select` returns simple `observable`, and not `BehaviorSubject`.
Your declaration should be :

```js
@Select(UserPageState.get('collection')) users$: Observable<User[]>;
```

or with `Partial<User>[]`, but I don't have details of your implementation

So If you just want to filter users retrieved by this selector:

```js
export class YourComponent {
  @Select(UserPageState.get('collection')) users$: Observable<User[]>;
  filteredUsers$: Observable<User[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    const USER = this.creds.credentials['id'];
    this.filteredUsers = this.users$.pipe(
      map(users => users.filter(user => user.id !== USER))
    );

    this.store.dispatch(new UserPageList({ start: 1, length: this.pageSize }));
  }
}
```

in your template:

```html
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers$ | async">
      {{ user.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Note that you should probably consider to create a **dedicated selector** and add `USER` in your store too.

Comment: where do I put the ```await this.store.dispatch(new UserPageList({ start: 1, length: this.pageSize })).toPromise();```

Comment: I've updated my answer because I think I better understand your issue. But I recommend you to read [https://www.ngxs.io/](ngxs docs) and also [https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular](Observables in Angular).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. It may be work
    import { of, Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

```
  private users$= new Subject<void>();
 onusers$: Observable<void>;


 this.onusers$ = this.users$.asObservable();


   this.users$.next(param:{param.filter(x => x.id !== USER))});
```