# Why use the RxJS .asObservable() getter/factory function pattern?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

In a lot of codebases using RxJS I seem to come across the pattern of exposing private `Subjects` as `Observables` via a `getter` or normal `getObservable()` function. My question is not why `.asObservable()` is used, but instead why it seems so commonly wrapped in a getter/factory function?

**asObservable() wrapped in getter/factory function**

---

```js
private readonly _engineInfo$ = new Subject<EngineInfo>();
get engineInfo$() { return this._engineInfo$.asObservable(); }
```

**asObservable() as instance variable**

---

```js
private readonly _engineInfo$ = new Subject<EngineInfo>();
public engineInfo$ = this._engineInfo$.asObservable();
```

**Questions**

---

- My undestanding is that `.asObservable()` creates a new `Observable` every time that subscribes to the `Subject`. Also the created `Observable` is *hot* and can be subscribed multiple times. **Why would one create multiple anonymous instances of `Observable`, *(one for each access/subscription)*, instead of having just one `Observable`, accessed at one class/service, that all observers subscribe to?**
- Is there a non-obvious advantage to this `getter/factory function` pattern?
- Could it be because of garbage collection or testing/mocking advantages?

So far I'm using the instance variable setup from the second example in all services/classes and everything seems to works as expected, also with multiple observers.

Comment: I must say, this is the first time I've ever heard of the getter factory pattern being considered as a commonly used pattern for observables. I assume the 2 suit different use cases and I would choose the one that suits you best.

Comment: I just called it a "pattern", since literally in every RxJS/Angular codebase (at my company) it seems to be the canonical way to access observables of subjects. So I assumed it must be quite popular, best practice and have some reason....!? Could you elaborate on the different use cases you mentioned? Why would you ever want a new `Observable` instance in practice as opposed to add another subscription to one central hot `Observable`?

Comment: I don't know! I would just reuse a single observable instance.

Comment: Subject IS an Observable, there is no need to perform such conversion. The code above can be used to disable calling `subject.next(something)`

Comment: Asking "_Why....?_" questions here is a risky business because they can easily be seen as inviting opinions, but I don't think that is the case for this question which has been carefully worded to invite technical arguments rather than opinion. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I've also seen implementation like the first one with "get new instance" using getter and my question is also the same: "Why would one create multiple anonymous instances of Observable". Are we fine with that or should we use a solution with single instance of Observable, like the second implementation suggests?

Answer (score 3):

## When to use Subject.prototype.asObservable()

The purpose of this is to prevent leaking the "observer side" of the Subject out of an API. Basically to prevent a leaky abstraction when you don't want people to be able to "next" into the resulting observable.

You never want to return a Subject instance to the calling context. Doing so would be somewhat akin to returning a Deferred object rather than a promise; and, it would leave the Subject open to unanticipated and corrupting usage. As such, when exposing a Subject, you'll probably want to convert it to an Observable first.

To get this working we can use the `Rx.Observable.prototype.asObservable()`instance method.

*The subject itself is hot/sharable* and it acts as a bridge/proxy between the source Observable and many observers, making it possible for multiple observers to share the same Observable execution.

Is there a non-obvious advantage to this getter/factory function pattern?
 Nope, not at all since you are Creating a new Observable with this Subject as the source to conceal it from code that uses the Observable.

[*When to use asObservable() in rxjs?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/5695162)

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! It may have been a little too detailed though, since, as stated in the orig. question, i'm aware of why/when to use `.asObservable()`. The main point of the question was to uncover if there is any use wrapping it up in `getter/factory functions` so that every client gets a new `Observable`, as opposed to every client subscribing to the same `Observable`. You answer that too, but not very prominently at the end. If you consider making this part more prominent, i would possibly upvote your answer. _(Not yet accept though, in case something comes up)_.

Comment: I think, instead of using a getter, using a read only instance _piped_ by `shareReplay(1)` (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) can do the job. I got the idea from https://www.gushiciku.cn/pl/2dLx

Comment: Ok, no advantage. Is there some disadvantage, or are any other concerns using multiple instances of Observables?