# How to pass data from modal to calling angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, angular-forms, mat-dialog

**callingmodal.component.ts**

```
export class CallingmodalComponent implements OnInit {
    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SharemodalComponent, {
          width: '640px', disableClose: true
        });
        console.log(dialogRef);

      }
}
```

**sharemodalComponent.component.ts**

```
export class SharemodalComponent implements OnInit {
  onaddCus(): void {
    console.log(this.sharingWith);
    console.log(this.addCusForm.value.selectedPermissionType);
  }
}
```

Upon one button click, I call **onaddCus()**. In this function I want to pass this.sharingWith and this.addCusForm.value.selectedPermissionType to callingmodal.component.ts.

How do I pass this parameters to callingmodal.component.ts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're dynamically creating `sharemodalComponent` from `callingmodal`. In that case, you could share data between them using a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). Try the following

shared.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SharedService {
  private _sharingWithSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  private _selectedPermissionTypeSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  
  public sharingWith$ = this._sharingWithSource.asObservable();
  public selectedPermissionType$ = this._selectedPermissionTypeSource.asObservable();

  set sharingWithSource(value: any) {
    this._sharingWithSource.next(value);
  }

  set selectedPermissionTypeSource(value: any) {
    this._selectedPermissionTypeSource.next(value);
  }
}
```

sharemodalComponent.component.ts

```js
export class SharemodalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }
  
  onaddCus(): void {
    this.sharedService.sharingWithSource = this.sharingWith;
    this.sharedService.selectedPermissionTypeSource = this.addCusForm.value.selectedPermissionType;
    console.log(this.sharingWith);
    console.log(this.addCusForm.value.selectedPermissionType);
  }
}
```

And in the calling modal component, subscribe in the `ngOnInit` hook to capture all the pushed notifications to the observables.

callingmodal.component.ts

```js
export class CallingmodalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  completed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.sharingWith$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$)
    ).subscribe(
      value => {
        if (value) {           // <-- default value is `null`
          this.sharingWith = value 
        }
      }
    );
 
    this.sharedService.selectedPermissionType$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$)
    ).subscribe(
      value => {
        if (value) { 
          this.selectedPermissionType = value 
        }
      }
    );
  }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SharemodalComponent, {
      width: '640px', disableClose: true
    });
    console.log(dialogRef);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.completed$.next();           // <-- close the observables
    this.completed$.complete();
  }
}
```

#### Update - explanation

1. RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) - A variant of the multicast observable RxJS `Subject`. It can hold the current data pushed to it and emit it immediately upon subscription. That is the reason it requires an initial value (we use `null` here) and we check before we assign the value.
2. `next` method of the behavior subject is used to push a new value to the observable. Other valid methods to push notifications are `error` and `complete`. Pushing to `error` will invoke the error callback in the observer and calling `complete` will complete the observable stream.
3. Whenever a subscription is involved, there is a potential memory leak from open/not-closed subscriptions. So it's always good practice to close the subscriptions in a component in it's `OnDestroy` hook. One way would be assign the subscription to a local variable and call `unsubscribe()` on it. Other elegant way is to use the RxJS [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator. More info about this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223749/6513921).
4. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/6513921) is a good explanation from a core member of the RxJS team on when to use `asObservable()` function.

Comment: HI Michael, Can you please explain the use of BehaviorSubject, .asObservable, .next, .takeUntil?

Comment: @PavithraMuthusamy: I've updated the answer to include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following constructur to your SharemodalComponent:

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
            public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SharemodalComponent>) {}
```

And than you can pass the data from your CallingmodalComponent and subscribe on the close event:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SharemodalComponent, {
      width: '640px', disableClose: true,
      data: { sharingWith: '100px', ... }
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result );
});
```

If you click your button you can close the dialoag and pass data to your CallingmodalComponent:

```
this.dialogRef.close('some data here');
```