# fixing a racecondition on rxjs subscription with shareReplay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to subscribe to an observable and log it's value.

Flow:

```
this.myObservable$ = new Subject<string>();
this.myObservable$.next('hello world') //in (angular) service A
```

wait a few seconds

```
let newObservable$ = this.myObservable$.asObservable().subscribe(message => console.log(message)); //subscribe in service B, nothing happens
```

But this didn't work since I subscribed too late. But even with a shareReplay this does not work.

```
let newObservable$ = this.myObservable$.asObservable()
      .pipe(
        shareReplay(1),
      )
      .subscribe(message => console.log(message)); //also nothing happens
```

Can anyone help me understand why I can't 'shareReplay' this observable and get the last emitted value?

Comment: Can't you just use a `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`? I think the `shareReplay` is only triggered when your Observable has a subscriber and further subscribers will receive the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `shareReplay` isn't working for you is because you are applying it to the derived observable, rather than the source.

You should apply it to the source:

```
this.mySubject$ = new Subject<string>();
this.myObservable$ = this.mySubject.asObservable.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

Now, your new observable will get the replayed value:

```
let newObservable$ = this.myObservable$.subscribe(
   message => console.log(message)
);
```

In your case, you were applying the `shareReplay` in the definition of `newObservable`, which will not achieve what you wanted.

As others have mentioned, since you already have a subject as a source, you could simply use a `ReplaySubject`:

```
this.mySubject$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
```

Normally, in the context of an Angular service, you would keep the `Subject` private on a service, and expose a readonly observable publicly to consumers.  Something like this:

Service:

```
private subject$ = new Subject();
public readonly value$ = this.subject$.pipe(shareReplay()) // if you use .pipe(), you don't really need .asObservable()
```

Component:

```
data$ = this.service.value$;
```

Since the `shareReplay` is defined on the source (`value$`) observable, the component will always get the replayed emission.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8tw2tq?devtoolsheight=60
I tried this but it also never logs to the console. Isn't this the same as your code?

Comment: It is not the same.  It actually has the same mistake! :-). Check out this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-sfxcet?file=index.ts) with a few notes.

Comment: ty very much for explaining again. But if I understand correctly it than is impossible to ever receive the 'testing-1' value?

Comment: It is possible, you just need to have a dedicated "source" observable to apply your `shareReplay` to.  That is why I separated the `subject$` from the `myObservable$`, so that `myObservable$` would be the source, to which you would apply the `shareReplay()` operator.

Comment: ok, derived2$ will receive values even though it subscribed after the source$.next emitted indeed… Hoowever for that you would first have to create a derived$ observable of source$ (which has the shareReplay). So if the source$ emits ("testing-1”) between the original and the derived$ observable (with the shareReplay), you can never catch that event right?

Comment: Correct.  Basically, the observable consumers actually use, needs to have the `shareReplay` applied.  So you want to define the `derived$` observable immediately after your subject, so that there's no chance for any emissions from subject that the observable doesn't receive.

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but here's a super basic example in an angular context: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzshrw?file=src/app/some.service.ts)

Comment: In angular context, i have a component whichs subscribes onInit to a subject from a service. However that service already emitted while the component is still rendering ... soo looks like there is an issue with the design.

Comment: The replay functionality would need to live  in the service. So hopefully it is a simple change to modify the service. Either by using replay subject. Or exposing an observable that uses shareReplay. :-)

Comment: This previous example works but I don't understand why, sincerelly.  How could I to shareReplay the 'testing-1' value in this example?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-byc2hc?file=index.ts

Comment: @SergiDoteTeixidor  Late subscribers won't receive prior emissions.  You can use [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) instead of `Subject`. Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66246196?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thank you, this one helped me. Suddenly `rxjs` subscriptions didn't work as it used to be even though there was no change in `package.json` neither that in the code (except moving few services around, however using `ReplaySubject` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple issues here

1. You could use `asObservable` method from a multicast like `Subject` to get the observable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36989035/6513921) for usage of `asObservable` from RxJS' core dev.
2. In the assignment `newObservable$ = this.myObservable$.subscribe(...)` you're actually assigning the subscription rather than the observable.
3. The issue at hand, `shareReplay` doesn't appear to work because it obviously isn't piped to the source initially but rather later. It'll work for the subsequent subscriptions.

Check the following illustration

```js
var { Subject, interval, fromEvent, of } = rxjs;
var { shareReplay } = rxjs.operators;

// Scenario 1 (analogous to OP's)

var subSource1 = new Subject();
var myObservable1$ = subSource1.asObservable();
myObservable1$.subscribe(m => console.log('Scenario 1: Initial subscription'));
subSource1.next('Hello world');
newObservable1$ = myObservable1$.pipe(
  shareReplay(1),
)
newObservable1$.subscribe(m => console.log(`Scenario 1: ${m}`));

// Scenario 2

var subSource2 = new Subject();
var myObservable2$ = subSource2.asObservable().pipe(
  shareReplay(1),
);
myObservable2$.subscribe(m => console.log('Scenario 2: Initial subscription'));
subSource2.next('Hello world');
newObservable2$ = myObservable2$;
newObservable2$.subscribe(m => console.log(`Scenario 2: ${m}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add a .asObservable() indeed to the beginning post. Added that now