# What is the difference between subscribing to subject and subscribing to asObservable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

What is the difference between subscribing to subject and subscribing to asObservable?

What is the difference between the following?

```
 this.subject.subscribe((data) => this.datas.push(data));
```

```
 this.subject.asObservable().subscribe((data) => this.datas.push(data));
```

Seems like both are same!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use asObservable() in rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986548/when-to-use-asobservable-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 2):

From the subscription side, there is no difference; emissions are received exactly the same.

`asObservable()` is used to hide the Observer behavior from consumers, preventing them from `next`ing values into the subject.

In angular, you'll see this in a lot services where you want consumers of the service to have access to the emitted values, but you don't want them to be able to call `.next` on the subject:

```
class SomeService {
    private subject$ = new Subject();
    public observable$ = this.subject$.asObservable();
}
```